# statements run in main but not when called from a function

Tags: c

Sorry. I really tried to solve this myself. But i don't understand. The statements ran okay when i place them in `main`. But when i call them in a function from `main`, segmentation fault happens. Does it mean memory overflowed?

```
void displayTime(char state[]) {
    time_t totalSec = time(NULL);//total no of secs since EPOCH
    struct tm *currTime = localtime(&totalSec); //store local time in struct declared in time.h
    char *result; 
    strftime(result, 20, "%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S", currTime); //E.g. 2017:11:12 12:30:48 Max is 20 characters including \0
    printf("Program at %s\n", result );
}

int main() {
    displayTime("started");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As a genral rule, code smell #1 that jumps out here is the parameter that you pass in but never use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allocate memory in `result` that is what is causing problem.

In your case it will be

```
result = malloc(sizeof(char)*BUFFSIZE);
if( result == NULL ){
   fprintf(stderr,"Error");
    exit(1);
}
```

There must be a corresponding `free` call to the allocated memory, here it will be

`free(result);`

Also accessing uninitialized variable is undefined behavior.

---

Also without `malloc` you can simply do this

```
char result[20];

strftime(result,20, "%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S", currTime);
```

---

Also my earlier edit with `state` is not possible. (Didn't notice that it's literal string) Since string literals belong to the read only section of memory. Now here we were trying to edit or modify it. That is wrong.

Secondly, even if it was not read only it will still not have memory to hold the characters that you would write. Because the size would not be big enough for that.

---

#### Further Explanation

To clarify the problem, look at the `result` variable. It is type `char*`. It is supposed to contain address of a char variable. Now when you declare it. Then it contains an indeterminate value.

Does it point to anything meaningful? No.

Now when you pass the variable to the function it tries to write something to a location whose address is contained in `result` variable. But it is not something useful and you will try to access some memory which is not even meant for you.(not permitted).

Segfaults are caused by a program trying read or write an illegal memory location.

That's what happened in your case.

#### Does it mean memory overflowed?

No. It has nothing to do with overflow.

---

Also what is the purpose of the `state` in your code? You are not using it anywhere in the code. You can avoid it.

Comment: Sorry. I am quite new to C. Can you explain why do i need to allocate memory for result when in a method, but not in main?

Comment: @Anlinyang.; in both cases. You can't pass an empty `char*` you need to allocate memory otherwise where d you think the characters will be written. That's why.

Comment: so everytime i use char * for a string, i need to allocate memory for it from the heap? But in main, the compiler did it for you?

Comment: @Anlinyang.: Yes where you need to have memory..yes.

Comment: `malloc` is overkill for this, especially given that the static buffer is already there for use.

Comment: so besides malloc(), i can declare the char * result as static? So it will stay in static memory after the method is returned?

Comment: @coderredoc. You can't do that. `state` is read only and more importantly, fewer than 20 chars.

Comment: @Anlinyang. Don't make it static just declare `char result[20];` instead of `char *result;`

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you. That cleared some of my misunderstandings.

Comment: @MadPhysicist.: I took 5 min to write the answer..seeing in mobile. So really hard.

Comment: The important thing to understand is that you didn't assign `result` any particular value. So it's a pointer that doesn't point to anything in particular and has no particular value. You then pass its value to `strftime` -- but it has a nonsense value. You need to assign a variable a value before you attempt to use its value.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz.:do you think I  should add this comment in my own words? I will be glad to do it. But it will be slow as I'm not in machine.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz.: I have edited to add a bit more detail. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
//char * result; // this is just a pointer with no memory to point to
char result[256] = {0,}; // now this will work
strftime(result, 20, "%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S", currTime);//E.g. 2017:11:12 12:30:48 Max is 20 characters including \0
```

alternatively

```
//char * result; // this is just a pointer with no memory to point to
char *result = malloc( 256 * sizeof(char));
if( result ) 
{
    strftime(result, 20, "%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S", currTime);//E.g. 2017:11:12 12:30:48 Max is 20 characters including \0
}
```

Comment: well i thought it would cause buffer overflow more over that is anyway will be in read-only secion